# ASP.NET - Trying to save the database with the logged in user, instead of a dropdown of all users in "Create" Scaffold

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I have a hopefully simple question where I have a database that connects Users to Workouts, the Users table and functionality on the site works correctly but when I make the UserWorkout table and check the scaffolded "Create" page to start a new Workout, it gives me a dropdown of all Users, where I really just want it to automatically select the User logged onto the site by default. I'm having troubles understanding the Controller code to fix this.

My Create controller looks like this on default:

```
// GET: UserCurrWorkouts/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName");
        ViewBag.UserActiveWorkout = new SelectList(db.WorkoutExercises, "LinkId", "LinkId");
        return View();       
}
```

And I tried changing it to this, so that it would select the logged in user instead (and I then removed the dropdown list from appearing on the View):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{            
        var currentUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
        ViewBag.UserId = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == currentUser).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.UserActiveWorkout = new SelectList(db.WorkoutExercises, "LinkId", "WorkoutId");
        return View();
}
```

But it just gave an error on the `db.SaveChanges();` line of code, so at this point I'm just kinda lost on how I'm supposed to interact with the controller.

EDIT:
Here is my razor code in the Create page that I wish to remove that has a dropdown of all users:

```
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @* Eventually should not be able to select other users in the dropdown menu, but couldn't figure out how to implement this *@
            @Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

Comment: Post your razor code. Based on your question it would seem you are assigning your user object to the UserId, not the actual id. Perhaps `ViewBag.UserId = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == currentUser).FirstOrDefault().UserId;` would work.

Comment: Looks like that didn't work :( I didn't add razor code since it was what I was trying to get rid of completely in regards to a User dropdown table (or at least set it to a readonly box as the logged in user). I edited and included what the dropdown that shows all users looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I think this will help.

You still need to have the `UserId` in your razor page so it gets passed back to the controller when your form is submitted.

If you don't want it showing you can use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="@ViewBag.UserId" />
```

and in your controller:

```
// You didn't state exactly what you're using but generally you get the
// User from HttpContext
var currentUser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == currentUser).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.UserId = user.Id;
```